# Numbers not adding correctly in C++

Tags: c++

Hi I am in the middle of writing a piece of code to show collections per supplier. I cant get the fat content and basic payment to show correctly. can anyone help point me in the right direction?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\tNW-Dairies \n\n";

    //date declaration
    int totalDrugFails=0, noOfCollections=0;
    double pricePerLtr=0.225, basicPayment=0, collectionQty=0, fatContent=0,fatPayment=0,      totalPayment=0, paymentPerCollection;
    double totalFatPayment=0, penaltyDeducted=0, totalDeducted=0;
    char drugResult;

    //Floating output values
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);


        //input data
    cout <<"\n\n\tEnter number of collections (Between 10 & 31) : ";
    cin>>noOfCollections;

    while(noOfCollections < 10 || noOfCollections > 31)
    {
        cout<<"\n\n\tError! Please enter a number between 10 and 31 : ";
        cin>>noOfCollections;
    } 



    //input data

            for(int x = 1; x<=noOfCollections; x++)
    {
        collectionQty=0;
        paymentPerCollection=0;
        fatPayment=0;
        penaltyDeducted=0;
        cout <<"\n\n\tEnter collection quanity : ";
        cin>>collectionQty;
        paymentPerCollection=pricePerLtr*collectionQty;

        cout<<"\n\n\tEnter fat Content : (Greater than 0.1 and less than 2.5) : ";
        cin>>fatContent;cin.ignore(10,'\n');
        while (fatContent < 0.01 || fatContent > 2.5)
            {
            cout<<"\n\n\tError! Please enter a number between 0.1 and 2.5 : ";
            cin>>fatContent;cin.ignore(10,'\n');
            }

        if(fatContent>0.02 && fatContent<0.05)
        {
            fatPayment=collectionQty*0.005;
                        totalFatPayment+=fatPayment;

        }
        if (fatContent>=0.05 && fatContent<=0.9)
        {
            fatPayment=collectionQty*0.0075;            
            totalFatPayment+=fatPayment;
        }
        else(fatContent>0.9);
        {
            fatPayment=collectionQty*0.02;
            totalFatPayment+=fatPayment;

        }
                cout<<"\n\n\tDrug Failure  (Y or N) : ";
                cin>>drugResult;cin.ignore(10, '\n');
                drugResult=toupper(drugResult);

//validating that it is only Y or N entered
                while (drugResult != 'Y' && drugResult != 'N')
                {
                    cout<<"\n\n\tPlease enter either Y or N : ";
                    cin>>drugResult;cin.ignore(10, '\n');
                    drugResult=toupper(drugResult);
                }
     //if the drug test fails then they lose the payment for that collection
                if (drugResult=='Y')
                {
                    penaltyDeducted=paymentPerCollection+fatPayment;
                    totalFatPayment=0;
                    basicPayment=0;
                    totalDrugFails++;
                }
                basicPayment+=paymentPerCollection;
                totalFatPayment+=fatPayment;
                totalDeducted+=penaltyDeducted;
                totalPayment=basicPayment+totalFatPayment;

            }



        //Drug fails comes out correctly
    //totalDeducted works
//basicPayment is not working as it shoule

          cout<<"\n\n\n\tTotal Drug Fails : "<<totalDrugFails;
    cout<<"\n\n\n\tTotal deducted : "<<totalDeducted;
    cout<<"\n\n\n\tBasic Monthly payment : "<< char (156) << basicPayment;
    cout<<"\n\n\n\tTotal fat payment : "<<char (156) << totalFatPayment;
    cout<<"\n\n\n\tTotal payment : "<< char (156) << totalPayment;



    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If would be more clear if you format the code properly.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?  We are not mind readers.

Comment: Can you post some test cases, what the input / result should be?

Comment: What do you get for basicPayment? What do you expect?

Comment: sorry I am new to the site. basicPayment is coming out a little wrong. so number of collections is 10. it will loop round 10 times asking the user to input the collection quanity (10) fat content (1) and drug fail Y or N. If the drug fail is Y they lose the payment for that collection and it is added to the penalty deducted. the fat content is coming out at more than it should and so is the basic payment.

Comment: Can you cut down your code to that which is relevant to the problem? I'm pretty sure only *part* of the program is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `else` is totally bogus:

```
     else(fatContent>0.9);
```

1. It should be `else if`, not `else`.  If you have compiler warnings enabled, some compilers should warn that the statement `(fatContent > 0.9)` has no effect.
2. There's a semicolon there before the opening block after, so even if you did add the `if` keyword (ie. `else if (fatContent > 0.9);`), the `else` block is effectively empty due to that semicolon.  As a result, the code that follows in curly braces executes *unconditionally.*

If you rewrite this nested `if-else` as follows, do things start working correctly?

```
    if(fatContent>0.02 && fatContent<0.05)
    {
        fatPayment = collectionQty*0.005;
        totalFatPayment += fatPayment;

    } else if (fatContent>=0.05 && fatContent<=0.9)
    {
        fatPayment = collectionQty*0.0075;            
        totalFatPayment += fatPayment;
    } else if (fatContent>0.9)
    {
        fatPayment = collectionQty*0.02;
        totalFatPayment += fatPayment;
    }
```

Comment: yes :) I changed the if statement but also took out the totalFatPayment from the if statement as it was in here and also below. It is wor :)king now. Thank you

Comment: Cool.  If this solved it, be sure to up vote and mark the question answered so that it's no longer listed among the unanswered questions.  :-)

Comment: sorry :( tried it again and theres still something not right with the fat content total payment. its 1.50 over.

Comment: was the <0.02. should be <=0.02